# Nautilus Renaming Bug when pressing 'n' key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

I have what i can consider a Big Bug on Nautilus under Ubuntu Linux.

When I am in the process of renaming a file or a folder, if I press <kbd>n</kbd>, nautilus opens a new tab.

The effect is: I cannot include 'n' in the name of any file or folder.

I must use one of these tricks to do it:

- Open a terminal and do the rename there
- Use any other application where I can type the name, then go back to Nautilus and paste the text into the rename dialog.

How can I fix this?

How to reproduce the problem:

- Open Nautilus in Ubuntu Linux
- Create a new folder, or select an existing one, or do it with any file
- Try to rename it
- Try to put an `n` in the name
  Some Examples: configuration, content, install, need, name, none, nine, null, ...
  (any name containing one or more `n` cannot be typed)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which version of nautilus (`nautilus --version`)? Does this only happen with `n`? Not with `t` as well? I am just wondering if your Ctrl is stuck.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've somehow ended up with `n` as a shortcut to open a new tab instead of `Ctrl+t`.

Under Gnome 2, I believe you can edit the Nautilus shortcuts from the Gnome control center (preferences). You may have accidentally defined a shortcut without noticing if you had the [“Editable menu shortcut keys” preference set](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1449649) (you can disable it from the “Interface” tab in the Gnome preferences, or from Gconf (run `gconf-editor`), under `desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_access`).

Under Gnome 3, there doesn't seem to be a GUI to edit preferences. Check the file `~/.config/nautilus/accels`.

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus is showing a bug involving renaming files and iBus, [at least since 2014](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1385292). Now in 2017 the bug persists. I'm having similar problems in Debian+Gnome, when trying to rename files. I succeed in renaming the first 2 or 3 files, just to not being able to rename anything anymore. I press F2, the edit field appears, but the keyboard won't respond anymore.

Now, is this really a bug, or possibly some kind of industrial sabotage to avoid spread of free software, and the consequent change in the industry's philosophy, and also to hinder the development of other countries? (iBus is used to type languages different from English.) If you think I'm paranoid, then why such a ridiculous bug still persists after 3 years?